# jQuery and AJAX call for element have JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form which has only one `textarea` element.

We use this text area to pass JavaScript code and save it into a MySQL database using PHP.

It works fine with any text, but not with text which has the JavaScript

```
$(function(){

      $("#hotbar").submit(function(){
          $.ajax({type:'POST', 
            url: 'modules/hotbar.php', 
            data:$('#hotbar').serialize(),
            beforesubmit : function() {
              return $('#hotbar').validate().form();
               },
            success: function(response) {
            $('#action').html(response);
        }
    });

       return false ;   
      });


});
```

It works fine with any text only; when passing the JS code we want to save it does nothing and never lets the value pass to the PHP page

Comment: _"we want to save it do nothing and never let the value pass to the php page"_ - Could you rephrase that please? You're saying you want to both "save it" and "never let the value pass" - which is it? Also, doesn't "JS code" fall within the definition of "_any_ text"?

Comment: when i pass a javascript through the text area for example
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.hellobar.com/hellobar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
this code do not pass the ajax and when print it in php it show nothing but with other normal text like any thing it works and print the value
    new HelloBar(51019,71923);
</script>

Comment: What does "do not pass the ajax" mean? If you are able to "print it in php" _even if it shows nothing_ then the Ajax request must have at least reached the PHP page. Does the entered text end up in your database? If so, when you later echo it back for display you'd need to replace the `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without more detail, but I'd start by checking if either the jQuery validation plugin or some form processing component on the server-side is removing the script tags to try and protect you from Cross-site Scripting (XSS) attacks.